# c++ linking error on static const

Tags: c++

I am using gcc (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5. with the following code, I am getting linking error :

> /tmp/ccOeGgC9.o: In function `A::func()':
>
>   (.text+0x1b): undefined reference to`B::CONST_B'
>   (.text+0x23): undefined reference to `A::CONST_A'

### header:

```
class A {
    public:
    static const int CONST_A = 10;
    int func();
};
class B {
    public:
        static const int CONST_B = 20;
};
```

### cpp file (with linking error):

```
int A::func() {
    bool c = true;
    const int a = (c == true) ? B::CONST_B : CONST_A;
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

to fix the error, I have to write cpp file follow:

### cpp file(working):

```
int A::func() {
    bool c = true;
    int a = CONST_A;
    a = (c == true) ? B::CONST_B : a;
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

can you please explain why I can't compile first code?

Comment: I don't see how your example is giving the linker error. `CONST_B` and `CONST_A` aren't odr-used in that case. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e25fcbbc9d39dab

Comment: I tried it with newer version of gcc and I didn't see that linker error, but I can only compile my code with gcc (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5

Comment: @0x499602D2 these sort of ODR violations require no diagnostic, so a clean compile doesn't prove that the code is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class A {
    public:
    static const int CONST_A = 10;
    int func();
};
```

static members like `CONST_A` in this example must have their definition outside the class

like this

```
class A {
   public:
   static const int CONST_A = 10;
   int func();
};

const int A::CONST_A = 10;
```

Comment: If that was the case, I should see the linker error in both case, but only the first code gives error

Comment: @Masoud Not true. [Some violations of the ODR must be diagnosed by the compiler. Other violations, particularly those that span translation units, are not required to be diagnosed.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule#Summary)